How to link BigRock domain with AWS Amplify app? SSL certificate is already available with BigRock. Need help to configure domain in AWS Amplify
I have successfully deployed my project using AWS Amplify, and it is currently accessible via the default Amplify URL. I also own a domain name purchased from BigRock and would like to configure this domain to point to my AWS Amplify app.
i have tried several possible ways to make it work.
